# Warning: MyClass:NSObject does not implement key value observing? How can that be?

Tags: cocoa, compiler-warnings, key-value-observing

I just recently resumed work on a Cocoa project that I left a few months ago. Cocoa is a strange beast if you have not been using it for a while.

Anyway, at some point the compiler started dropping warnings:

> Incomplete implementation of class 'MyClass'
>   Method definition for '-addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context' not found
>   Method definition for '-removeObserver:forKeyPath:' not found
>   Class 'MyClass' does not fully implement the 'MyZoomScrollViewDataSource' protocol

But `MyClass` is derived from `NSObject`, which does in fact implement `-addObserver:forKeyPath:` and `-removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:`.

The protocol looks like this:

```
@protocol MyZoomScrollViewDataSource
    // The range of Data that should be shown. This corresponds to the horizontal  
    //   zoom and the scroll value of self.
    @property FRange selectionRange;

    // Also, make sure the dataSource is KVO compliant
    - (void)addObserver:(NSObject *)anObserver forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options context:(void *)context;
    - (void)removeObserver:(NSObject *)anObserver forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;
@end
```

The class looks like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <MyZoomScrollViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet Outlets...
    variables...
}
@properties...
(IBAction)actions...
- methods...
@end
```

I guess my Cocoa skills are in deep need for a refresh. But still, these methods should be inherited from `NSObject`, so how can `MyClass` not implement these methods?

Comment: Is `MyClass` the same as `NovaController`?

Comment: @Bavarious: Yes, it is. I corrected the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to this is to explicitly add those functions to the class. This seems rather hackish to me. I would gladly use a cleaner way to do this if there is one.

```
@implementation MyClass

- (void)addObserver:(NSObject *)anObserver forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options context:(void *)context {
    [super addObserver:anObserver forKeyPath:keyPath options:options context:context];
}

- (void)removeObserver:(NSObject *)anObserver forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath {
    [super removeObserver:anObserver forKeyPath:keyPath];
}

@end
```

The strangest thing is: This works not only with `super`, it works with `self`, too! Consider my mind blown. What the heck?

Comment: It works in the sense that it compiles or it works in the sense that it runs? That looks like a loop to me.

Comment: It runs without a hitch! It looks like a loop to me, too. Cocoa, what art thou doing?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the question!

The compiler warning:

```
-addObserver:forKeyPath:
-removeObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:
```

The protocol:

```
-addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:
-removeObserver:forKeyPath:
```

The second looks better.

Comment: Oh, my bad. That was a typo in the question. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to avoid those warnings by using the `-Wno-protocol` compiler option:

> If a class is declared to implement a protocol, a warning is issued for every method in the protocol that is not implemented by the class. The default behavior is to issue a warning for every method not explicitly implemented in the class, **even if a method implementation is inherited from the superclass.** If you use the `-Wno-protocol` option, then methods inherited from the superclass are considered to be implemented, and no warning is issued for them.

Comment: does that mean that you are officially discouraged to use methods inherited from the superclass?

Comment: @BastiBechtold Not necessarily. I think the compiler is being (overly) conservative because it could be the case that, for a given protocol, subclasses should also implement the protocol methods. Or maybe it is literally considering that a class (regardless of its superclasses) must implement the required methods in the protocols it adopts.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was hasty with my answer.

Why are you declaring the KVO methods in the protocol. NSObject already implements a basic version of them?

Comment: I do use those methods on the `DataSource`. If I don't declare them, I get `WARNING: '-removeObserver:forKeyPath:' not found in protocol(s)` right where I use them.

Comment: When you say `DataSource` you mean the `NovaController` class?

Comment: correct, I do. I corrected the question accordingly. It didn't really make too much sense until now, did it?